# MQSeries error with MQCONN on TESTQMGR - compcode = 2, reason = 2058

Tags: ibm-mq

I Am using Java application to connect to WMQ so as to create test suite, which pass message from a file to queue and wait for response from other queue, I am using WMQ V7.0 and ih03_RFHutil package provided by IBM, but after configuring every thing correctly I am getting below error message.  It looks like some Authentication issue. Can some one please help me in this.

Below is Logs I have taken using log4j:

```
2017-03-06 17:26:01 DEBUG Runner_TMH_Tester:108 - initial sleep time 20 tune = 0
2017-03-06 17:26:01 DEBUG Runner_TMH_Tester:108 - connecting to TESTQMGR
2017-03-06 17:26:01 DEBUG Runner_TMH_Tester:108 - MQSeries error with MQCONN on TESTQMGR - compcode = 2, reason = 2058
```

Comment: If my answer your question helped please follow the feedback in the Help Center article "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)". Specifically rather than say thank you, vote the answer up and accept the answer if it solved your problem. To accept you click the "Check Mark" that is below the down arrow under the number next to the question.

Answer (score 2):

MQ v7.0 was released June 27th 2008 and has been out of support since September 30th 2015 (almost 1.5 years).  The version probably does not have anything to do with your issue but I would strongly suggest that you move to a supported version of the MQ client.  Newer MQ client versions can connect to older MQ queue managers.  You can download a java only install of MQ 8.0 or MQ 9.0 jar files at the links below:

- [IBM MQ v8.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500)
- [IBM MQ v9.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176)

---

The MQ client and queue manager install come with a program called mqrc.  You can run this against the MQ return code, in this case 2058 to come up with a more meaning full description:

```
$ mqrc 2058

      2058  0x0000080a  MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR
```

This is telling you that `TESTQMGR` is not the name of the queue manager that exists on the host and port you are connecting too.  Verify the queue manager name, hostname, and port are all correct.